# How to check whether a MIME type is of JPG, PNG, BMP or GIF?

Tags: php, mime-types, fileinfo

I have written this code:

```
$filename = "some/path/where/the/file/can/be/found.some_extension";
$buffer = file_get_contents($filename);
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
var_dump($finfo->buffer($buffer));
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Possible outputs were of:

```
"image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/x-ms-bmp"
```

I would like to know, what are the possible outputs of `$finfo->buffer($buffer)`, if the file is a png, gif, bmp, or jpg?

I have seen [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) a `returnMIMEType` function, which, for instance will not detect `"image/x-ms-bmp"` to be a bmp.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: Don't use the `mime_content_type`; It is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin, but I have linked to the manual in my question, so I believe it is obvious that I have already looked at the manual.

Comment: Thanks, antoox, for the tip, but I am not using it. I just try to find the possible mime types, which might be the return values of the $finfo->buffer($buffer) function. So far, I had no luck.

Comment: all the possible MIME types? you have a list here for example, but I don't know how updated it is xDD http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot find image/x-ms-bmp there, for instance.

Comment: This site has it simply did a google search for "x-ms-bmp mime type",
http://filext.com/file-extension/BMP

Comment: You can use their site search for the other file types.

Comment: Pitchinnate, have you considered to move your comment to the answers section, so I can accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can view the possible MIME types of file extensions by searching for the file extension at the link provided by Pitchinnate. For instance BMP MIME types can be found at: filext.com/file-extension/BMP

Answer (score -1):

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918761/php-get-file-type-by-url) thread, you can find some useful suggestions and functions for your situation.