# PHP- Get file type by URL

Tags: php, file

I want to get the file type (eg. image/gif) by URL using PHP.I had tried

```
<?php
$image_path="http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/227/4/6/PNG_Test_by_Destron23.png";
exif_imagetype($image_path);
?>
```

The above code gave me a blank page and the following code returned "3":

```
<?php
$image_path="http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/227/4/6/PNG_Test_by_Destron23.png";
echo exif_imagetype($image_path);
?>
```

Where am I going wrong?
Solved: using Fileinfo to fetch content type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?php
 $image_path="http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/227/4/6/PNG_Test_by_Destron23.png";
 echo exif_imagetype($image_path);
?>
```

It returned `3` because `png` response type as maciej said.

Try this to get like this `image/png`:

```
echo mime_content_type($image_path);
```

Try this:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension   
echo finfo_file($finfo, $image_path) . "\n";
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Comment: When I store url in $image_path it says: Warning: mime_content_type($image_path) [function.mime-content-type]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/appfesti/public_html/y.php on line 4

Comment: yes it is deprecated... $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

Comment: @jGrice  Can I use fileinfo with url?

Comment: got it?@AshishSrivastava

Comment: @user3923716 When I used URL i got **Warning: finfo_file() [function.finfo-file]: Failed identify data 0:(null)**. So I decided to store the file on my server instead of querying with url :)

Comment: @Avis Can you provide System info where you was able to successfully run finfo_open() by URL?

Answer (score 18):

Here is a PHP function I came up with:

```
/**
 * @param $image_path
 * @return string|null
 */
function get_image_mime_type(string $image_path):?string
{
    $mimes  = [
        IMAGETYPE_GIF => "image/gif",
        IMAGETYPE_JPEG => "image/jpg",
        IMAGETYPE_PNG => "image/png",
        IMAGETYPE_SWF => "image/swf",
        IMAGETYPE_PSD => "image/psd",
        IMAGETYPE_BMP => "image/bmp",
        IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II => "image/tiff",
        IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM => "image/tiff",
        IMAGETYPE_JPC => "image/jpc",
        IMAGETYPE_JP2 => "image/jp2",
        IMAGETYPE_JPX => "image/jpx",
        IMAGETYPE_JB2 => "image/jb2",
        IMAGETYPE_SWC => "image/swc",
        IMAGETYPE_IFF => "image/iff",
        IMAGETYPE_WBMP => "image/wbmp",
        IMAGETYPE_XBM => "image/xbm",
        IMAGETYPE_ICO => "image/ico"];

    if (($image_type = exif_imagetype($image_path))
        && (array_key_exists($image_type ,$mimes)))
    {
        return $mimes[$image_type];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I get this code and works! thanks. Only copy and paste. workfull!

Comment: The question is `PHP- Get file type by URL` - this answer only handles image URLs.

Answer (score 15):

the best way for my understanding

```
if (!function_exists('getUrlMimeType')) {
    function getUrlMimeType($url)
    {
        $buffer = file_get_contents($url);
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        return $finfo->buffer($buffer);
    }
}
```

is to create function depend on [finfo class](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.finfo.php)

Comment: This should be the approved answer. It's the cleanest imo

Comment: This gets the filetype, e.g. `video/quicktime` for `mov` files.

Answer (score 6):

You are not going wrong anywhere. `exif_imagetype` returns the value of one of the image type constants: http://php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php

If you would like to convert this to an extension string, you could use a switch statement:

```
$typeString = null;
$typeInt = exif_imagetype($image_path);
switch($typeInt) {
  case IMG_GIF:
    $typeString = 'image/gif';
    break;
  case IMG_JPG:
    $typeString = 'image/jpg';
    break;
  case IMG_JPEG:
    $typeString = 'image/jpeg';
    break;
  case IMG_PNG:
    $typeString = 'image/png';
    break;
  case IMG_WBMP:
    $typeString = 'image/wbmp';
    break;
  case IMG_XPM:
    $typeString = 'image/xpm';
    break;
  default: 
    $typeString = 'unknown';
}
```

You may want to change the order to most to least frequently expected for better performance.

Comment: The `IMG_JPG` case should be removed, `image/jpg` is not a valid MIME type.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, you're getting a blank page because you're not doing anything with the return value from the function call. In the second example, you're getting a valid response. See [the manual page for exif_imagetype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) for a list of what the values mean.

Comment: thanx for the link, we can use `image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($url))` to get the `'image/xxx'` mime type

Answer (score 2):

[exif_imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) returns the image type. The response, 3, indicates it is IMAGETYPE_PNG, the correct response.

Comment: isnt it possible to get output like "image/png"?

Comment: You can either hard code a switch and compare the value against it, or use finfo_file to get the MIME type (image/png)

Answer (score 1):

3 is image type response for PNG image. See:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

Comment: isnt it possible to get output like "image/png"?

Comment: then you have to write...mime_content_type @AshishSrivastava

Comment: @user3923716 I get: Warning: mime_content_type() [function.mime-content-type]: Failed identify data 0:(null) in /home/appfesti/public_html/y.php on line 4